# google.appengine.api.search Cursor ignored

Tags: google-app-engine

In my experience with the GAE 1.7 Python SDK, the cursor feature of the new Search API isn't working. I can get back a cursor from a search() allright, but passing it in a second call produces a result that does not exclude what I've already received. I modified http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search/python/search_demo.py as follows to show this:

```
    query_options = search.QueryOptions(
        limit=2,
        sort_options=sort_opts,
        cursor=search.Cursor())
    query_obj = search.Query(query_string=query, options=query_options)
    results = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query=query_obj)
    if results.number_found > len(results.results):
        query_obj = search.Query(query_string=query, options=search.QueryOptions(cursor=results.cursor))
        results = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME).search(query=query_obj)
```

Have anyone found this to be working as you would expect?

Comment: What exactly are you getting? I couldn't reproduce your problem,  because I got an error when executing the second query (sort_options are omitted). See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Passing_Queries_in_a_Query_Object for a complete example. When following the example or when adding the sort_options to your code it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

this was a bug fixed with the latest SDK
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8254